# Tachanun on friday and sunday

Tags: halacha, tachanun

I heard that in some Chassidic communities they don't say tachanun on Friday morning to prepare for Shabbat and on Sunday morning either to "recover" from Shabbat, is that true?
and if this is true what are the Halachic sources

Comment: There isn't a halachic source. They made it up. (To some degree all matters of omitting tachanun are just questions of minhag, and every minhag was made up at some point.)

Comment: You know the famous joke that real Chassidim don’t say tachanun any day of the year, because every day of the year is a holiday and special day because some rabbi was saved from prison or death or whatnot. One day the rabbi of the shul couldn’t find any miracle or saving of a rebbe that happened on the day and asked the gabbai “so should we say tachanun today?” The gabbai then said “if no rebbe was saved today, that means today was a day when no rebbe was ever in danger! No tachanun required!”